# SQLAlchemy MutableDict with Postgres JSON column not firing "set" event

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

(SQLAlchemy 1.0.11, Python 2.7)

Column definition in model:

`public_data = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(JSON), nullable=False)`

Event listener in same model file:

```
def __listener(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    ... do some stuff

event.listen(User.public_data, 'set', __listener)
```

Change that should trigger `set` event:

```
# this doesn't work
user.public_data['address'] = ''

# but this works
user.public_data = {}
```

The event is never triggered when only a JSON attribute is modified. I stepped through the SQLAlchemy code and found that after the above line is executed, the model's `changed()` method is called, which I assume should be responsible for the event firing. Am I doing something wrong or is this not supported?

Comment: Does work for me in both cases using the same version of sqlalchemy and python 3.4.3. But I doubt that the difference in python version is causing this.

Comment: For real? I filed a bug for SQLAlchemy regarding this and they turned it into a feature request: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3617/add-a-new-attributeevent-for-the-generic

Comment: And a full example: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/0xANDREW/9doBM

Comment: You are right. I missed the fact that during initial instance creation the event was triggered as well, so still had a count of 2.